# Representing a Lexicographic Preference in a Natural X Natural Choice Space With Utility Function

Tags: mathematical-economics, utility, preferences, proof, discrete-preferences

[image]

my current thinking is i have to dis/prove two things

1. cardinality
2. continuity
   but im not sure about how it would apply since the above is a natural X natural choice space

I know cardinality of natural choice space = cardinality of rational numbers, but im not sure how I can relate that to representation in a utility function

Im not sure about continuity because epsilon balls around numbers in a natural space doesnt include anything else

Comment: Have you tried writing down a few bundles and seeing if there is a way to compare them? Try out out some examples and it should be clear if such a representation is possible.

Comment: No it doesn't. The link you provide shows an example where they are comparing real to rational as a proof, whereas my question is set in the natural choice space @Giskard

Comment: @WalrasianAuctioneer yeah, the lexicographic preference can be compared by drawing but im not sure how i can prove that

Comment: Sorry, mistake! But why are you bringing continuity into this? It is not required that $U$ is continuous, is it?

Comment: @Giskard my lecture notes state that discontinuous preferences cannot be represented by a utility function, hence the continuity argument

Comment: I am afraid your lecture notes are mistaken in this instance.

Comment: E.g., the *sign* function defines discontinuous preferences over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Giskard okay, if we assume to ignore the continuity statement, do you have any suggestions as to how I would proceed with the first point?

Comment: I posted an answer 10 minutes ago (:

Comment: At first I linked the wrong question, but here is a true duplicate: [Lexicographic Preference Relation on the QxR](https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/24415/1601)

Comment: @Giskard Can I ask about the significance of the first line in your answer below? I don't really understand how we can map the entire natural plane in [0,1)

Comment: You don't understand the function that assigns $1 - 1/(y+1)$ to $y$? What do you not understand about it? Do you think this can go under 0 or above 1? Note that it is not about the natural *plane*, just natural numbers.

Comment: @Giskard Sorry, not the function, but I dont think I understand the significance or implications of Take a strictly increasing mapping f:N→[0,1)
What are we doing here and why can we map the natural plane as [0,1)?

Comment: It does not map the natural plane, just natural numbers. I suggest you take  
WalrasianAuctioneer's advice and experiment by plugging in some numbers, e.g., is (2,0) preferred to (1,99) according to this function?

Comment: @Giskard okay after prolonged thinking I believe I understand most of it. do you think it is necessary for me to state the cardinality stuff? as the question asks to show all details of your claim and proof

Comment: I cannot speak for your university program, but I am sure you can talk about the exact requirements with your professor.

Comment: @Giskard thank you so much for your help! I understand it now

Answer (score 4):

Take a strictly increasing mapping $f:\mathbb{N} \to [0,1)$, such as
$$
f(y) = 1 - \frac{1}{y+1}.
$$
Then
$$
U(x,y) = x + f(y)
$$
represents the Lexicographic preference in the $\mathbb{N}^2$ choice space.