# Example to Demonstrate that with Uncountably Infinite Outcomes We do not Have A Representing Utility Function

Tags: utility, preferences

Suppose we define $\Omega$ = $\mathbb R_+$. The preference relation $\succeq $ is defined as $$(x_1, x_2)\succeq(y_1,y_2)\iff x_1>y_1 \text{ or } [x_1=y_1 \text{ and }x_2\geq y_2]$$
where $x_1, x_2,y_1, y_2\in \mathbb R_+$

How to prove that there does not exist utility function that represents this preference?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: @Giskard. I don't think that this question is a duplicate, because it points out the relevance of the uncountability of the sets on which the preference relation is defined. Lexicografic preferences **can** be represented by a utlity function if they are defined on $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{R}$, as $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable. See https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/24415/lexicographic-preference-relation-on-the-qxr?rq=1e. This is ia subtle but  important issue, because it is not true that lexicografic preferences cannot be represented by a utility function in general.

Comment: I didn't find a question on SE that addresses *specifically* this issue.

Comment: @BakerStreet Thanks for the clarification. I guess in the example case it provides a counterexample for uncountable outcomes. The proof on the other thread sounds good to me.

Comment: You are welcome. I wanted to point out tha there are proofs for the case of uncountable sets that fail if applied to countable sets.